# Perl Moose default value not set

Tags: perl, moose

I am using strawberry perl
Moose 2.0010

In the class:

```
package Cat;
use 5.010;
use strict;
use Moose;

has 'name',       is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => 'Beauty';
#has 'age',       is => 'ro';
has 'diet',       is => 'rw', default => 'fish';
has 'birth_year', is => 'ro', isa=> 'Int',
                  default => 1997;
sub age
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $year = (localtime)[5] + 1900;

    return $year - $self->birth_year();
}
```

In the application:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use Cat;

my $kitty = Cat->new();
say 'I have a kitten named ', $kitty->name(), ' eats ', $kitty->diet(),
    'in age ', $kitty->age();
```

Output:

> Use of uninitialized value in
>   subtraction (-) at Cat.pm line 16. I
>   have a kitten named  eats  in age 2011
>   Press any key to continue . . .

The default value not set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your other question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434597/perl-moose-attribute-not-force-type-checking) shows what the problem is after you showed the full source to `Cat.pm`.  You had a stray `new` method defined which overrode the `new` method which `Moose` supplies.  Remove that stray `new` method, and it works just fine.

Comment: @Weiyan - if you want to override `new()` using Moose, then look at `BUILDARGS` and `BUILD` : http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Construction.pod

Answer (score 3):

`$year` is just fine, as is `(localtime)[5]`.

The problem is that your object hasn't been initialized for some reason.  Namely, $self->birth_year() is coming back undefined.

If you look at your output, "have a kitten named eats in age 2011", you're missing the name, what it eats, and the age is 2011 - 0 (or just 2011 if I remember my subtraction tables).  Since undef is treated as 0, you have issues to take care of before worrying about the age calculation.

Also, I ran your code, and you are either not telling us something, or this is a paraphrase of your actual code.  When I ran it, I got the expected results:  "I have a kitten named Beauty eats fish birth at 1997 aged 14"

One of the reasons I believe this is because you didn't include the trailing `1;` in `Cat.pm`, so as it is, it won't even compile.